# How do I use different category template in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am using Twenty twelve theme in wordpress to make a project. To display various styles of  pages I can choose custom page template page, but I have to use category instead of pages.
But how I make different category template and use them ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in almost exactly the same way as you would do with pages.
Just follow the Wordpress Template Hierarchy:

"category-slug.php"
"category-ID.php"
etc
http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

So, if you have a category with the name "**cars**", the name of template for that category should be "category-**cars**.php" :)

Edit: a few minutes too late :(

Comment: Could you approve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can check category by id and use native function where it needed.

`get_template_part( 'custom_category', 'category' );` 
Also You can try something from here [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

Comment: Sorry Dear,
I have found my way...
I just created a new category file named "category-(slug name).php" and it automatically found the default category of its own. I just customize the category-template to show different styles of pages.
Thanks for trying to help me, Valery Statichny.

Comment: @Nirjhar Mandal, Nice and elegant solution !